# Book Recommendation for SharePoint Online Search (Microsoft Search) from scratch to Pro

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, microsoft-search

Am looking for some books, Online courses specific to SharePoint Online Search (Microsoft Search), any recommendations please? Also, I was looking at this course by Agnes Molnar (https://searchexplained.teachable.com/) Any thoughts please? I am an Office 365 consultant with good knowledge on general concepts of SharePoint but looking for some solid foundations on Microsoft Search for better customer delivery.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to read Microsoft's official documentation on SharePoint Search.

[Overview of search in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/overview-of-search)